# Use a custom 3D graphic for points in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to make a plot where the points of `ListPointPlot3D` are themselves a `Graphics3D` object created using `SphericalPlot3D`, and each one depends on the position of the point.  So basically, you have a list of points, `{x, y, z}`, and at each point there is a graphic which is determined by a function $f(x_i, y_i, z_i)$.  I have been searching for about a day now to try and find a solution to this with no luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I don't have to use `ListPointPlot3D`, and if there is a better method I would certainly welcome it.

Comment: You might want to check out `BubbleChart3D` and `ChartElements`

Comment: @chuy I think that's worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try using `BubbleChart3D` along with the `ChartElements` option.  For example:

```
element = 
 SphericalPlot3D[
  1 + Sin[5 \[Phi]]/5, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 10]], 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None];

BubbleChart3D[RandomReal[1,{10,4}], ChartElements->element]
```

[image]

The caveat here will be that BubbleChart3D expects data in the form of {x,y,z,u}, wehre u will be used to determine the size of the "bubble". If you don't care about that just set them all equal to 1 or something.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make some 3D object to use as the point.  I'm lazy so I lifted this from the docs:

```
obj = First@SphericalPlot3D[1 + 2 Cos[2 θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

(It's important that this object should be centred around the origin $(0,0,0)$.)

Generate points:

```
pts = RandomReal[20, {10, 3}];
```

Use `Translate` to place the object at the positions of the points:

```
Graphics3D@Translate[obj, pts]
```

[image]