# Plot markers for ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, visualization, marker

I suffer a little bit of color blindness, that is the reason why I always prefer to have plots with markers instead of different colors. For instance, I do not like the look of this:

```
iris = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"];
ListPlot[Values[#], PlotLegends -> Keys[#]]& @ 
  GroupBy[iris, Last -> (First[#][[1 ;; 2]] &)]
```

[image]

but largely prefer:

```
ListPlot[Values[#], PlotLegends -> Keys[#], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]& @ 
  GroupBy[iris, Last -> (First[#][[1 ;; 2]] &)
```

[image]

However, AFAIK the `PlotMarkers` option is not available for `ListPointPlot3D`

```
ListPointPlot3D[Values[#], PlotLegends -> Keys[#]]& @ 
  GroupBy[iris, Last -> (First[#][[1 ;; 3]] &)]
```

[image]

My question: how can I have markers (similar to those available for 2D list plots) in `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: The markers used in `ListPlot` and its ilk are special text characters, which is OK for 2D plots, but unsuited for use in 3D plots. That is likely to be why they not supported. The only solution I can think of is to replace the points comprising the plot with insets of 3D graphics objects such as spheres, cubes, and other polyhedra. That is tedious and largely destroys the convenience of `ListPointPlot3D`, so I suspect it's not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks for the clarifications, if you want to turn this to an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I am reluctant to do that because I think my comment is, as you say, a clarification, not an answer. A real answer would supply code for making the insets and installing them in the plot. I don't have time to work that out at the moment. Perhaps someone else will tackle it.

Comment: As an aside: since you seem to like to write concise code, you might want to replace  `Last -> (First[#][[1 ;; 2]] &` with `Last -> (#[[1, ;; 2]] &)` and `Last -> (First[#][[1 ;; 3]] &)` with `Last -> (#[[1, ;; 3]] &)`

Comment: @m_goldberg again thanks for the tip! Best,Vincent

Comment: You will be interested in: [Point style in ListPointPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48626/27951) and in: [Use a custom 3D graphic for points in ListPointPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40849/27951), which I think are near-duplicates of your request.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks I will have a look (I need to leave office right now)